# How to use raw sql Pagination in Laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

This is my Controller code:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,earth_distance(ll_to_earth(team.lat, team.lng), ll_to_earth(23.1215939329,113.3096030895)) AS distance FROM team where earth_box(ll_to_earth(23.1215939329,113.3096030895),1000) @> ll_to_earth(team.lat, team.lng); ";
$result = DB::select( \DB::raw( $sql ) );
```

How can I add pagination to this code to build my restful api?

iOS or android will send the "next page" parameter, how to use it and find the next section data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know you can't paginate raw query, here's why:

```
$result = DB::select($sql);
```

`$result` here will have the array type and `paginate()` is the method from the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class.

Your case can be performed this way:

```
$items = DB::table('team')   
    ->selectRaw('SELECT *,earth_distance(ll_to_earth(team.lat, team.lng), ll_to_earth(23.1215939329,113.3096030895)) AS distance')
    ->whereRaw('earth_box(ll_to_earth(23.1215939329,113.3096030895),1000) @> ll_to_earth(team.lat, team.lng)')
    ->paginate(10);

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item->distance;
}
```

As you can see minimal effort is needed here to separate raw query to `selectRaw()` and `whereRaw()` methods.

Comment: @Kenny you can accept my answer for further readers if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you are trying to paginate dynamic columns that maybe you were processing calculations on for reporting is to create a sort method and pass in your array and params:

```
public function sort($array_of_objects, $sort_by=null, $order, $page) 
{
    $collection = collect($array_of_objects);
    if ($sort_by)
    {

        if ($order=='desc') {
            $sorted = $collection->sortBy(function($role) use ($sort_by)
            {
                return $role->{$sort_by};
            })->reverse();
        } else if ($order=='asc') {
            $sorted = $collection->sortBy(function($role) use ($sort_by)
            {
                return $role->{$sort_by};
            });
        }
    } else {
        $sorted = $collection;
    }

    $num_per_page = 20;
    if (!$page) {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $offset = ( $page - 1) * $num_per_page;
    $sorted = $sorted->splice($offset, $num_per_page);

    return  new Paginator($sorted, count($array_of_objects), $num_per_page, $page);

}
```