# Laravel Paginate usage with DB::raw query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination

How I can use paginate() with this query?

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw(" select a.user_id, a.user_email, 
a.user_account_status, a.created_at, b.s_account_limit AS account_limit,
 c.consumed_limit, ((b.s_account_limit*1024) - c.consumed_limit) AS 
remaining_limit FROM upload_limits as b, users AS a JOIN user_upload_limits as 
c WHERE (a.user_id=c.user_id) AND a.user_type='Simple'"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use raw sql Pagination in Laravel5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968354/how-to-use-raw-sql-pagination-in-laravel5)

Comment: Short answer: You can't paginate a raw query in Laravel, but there are workarounds.

Comment: $pagination = Paginator::make($book, count($book), 5);

Comment: Paginator is not working as well. plz suggest something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `->paginate()` method or if you want to create a pagination manually, you would do something like:

```
$perPage = $request->input("per_page", 10);
$page = $request->input("page", 1);
$skip = $page * $perPage;
if($take < 1) { $take = 1; }
if($skip < 0) { $skip = 0; }

$basicQuery = DB::select(DB::raw(" select a.user_id, a.user_email, a.user_account_status, a.created_at, b.s_account_limit AS account_limit, c.consumed_limit, ((b.s_account_limit*1024) - c.consumed_limit) AS remaining_limit FROM upload_limits as b, users AS a JOIN user_upload_limits as c WHERE (a.user_id=c.user_id) AND a.user_type='Simple'"));
$totalCount = $basicQuery->count();
$results = $basicQuery
    ->take($perPage)
    ->skip($skip)
    ->get();

$paginator = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($results, $totalCount, $take, $page);

return $paginator;
```

Comment: Thanks; much appreciated.

Comment: Undefined variable: take

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a custom sort method that you pass in your array result of DB::raw along with your params:

```
    public function sort($array_of_objects, $sort_by=null, $order, $page) 
{
    $collection = collect($array_of_objects);
    if ($sort_by)
    {

        if ($order=='desc') {
            $sorted = $collection->sortBy(function($role) use ($sort_by)
            {
                return $role->{$sort_by};
            })->reverse();
        } else if ($order=='asc') {
            $sorted = $collection->sortBy(function($role) use ($sort_by)
            {
                return $role->{$sort_by};
            });
        }
    } else {
        $sorted = $collection;
    }

    $num_per_page = 20;
    if (!$page) {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $offset = ( $page - 1) * $num_per_page;
    $sorted = $sorted->splice($offset, $num_per_page);

    return  new Paginator($sorted, count($array_of_objects), $num_per_page, $page);

}
```