# Transforming raw MySql query result to Laravel collection (hydrateRaw)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I am trying to get the Laravel Pagination work with the results I receive from my database using a raw query:

```
select sub.*, count(l.PRODID) as likecount
from (
    select p.*, count(c.PRODID) as commentcount
    from products p
    left join comments c on c.PRODID = p.ID
    group by p.ID
) sub 
left join likes l on l.PRODID = sub.ID
group by sub.ID
```

But while the result is a plain array, the paginate() function won't work.

I have found the hydrateRaw method in the docs, But no matter how I try it throws me an error.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the selectRaw method on the Eloquent model. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321497/how-to-use-pagination-in-laravel-5-with-raw-query

Comment: with DB facade http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968354/how-to-use-raw-sql-pagination-in-laravel5

Comment: Thanks, indeed using facades it can be done, but I would like to learn the usage of hydrate() and hydrateRaw() to have it in my tools belt for the future.

Comment: Did you try using like this: `$model->hydrateRaw($query, [])`?

Comment: if I try inside my controller: `$model = \App\Product; $model->hydrateRaw($query, [])` with the above query - get: **Undefined constant 'App\Product'**

Comment: `hydrate()` and `hydrateRaw()` are static methods. You should call them like this, `\App\Product::hydrate()`/`\App\Product::hydrateRaw()`

Comment: `$model = \App\Product;` this not valid PHP. You should create new instance with `new`

Comment: @Doom5 thanks, my wrong, now I get the collection as output, for `\App\Product::hydrateRaw("select sub.*, count(l.PRODID) as likecount
from ( select......etc ", [])->paginate(15);` - but it seems paginate() does not like it, it throws: **BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method paginate does not exist.**

Comment: @Edmond The methods `hydrate()` and `hydrateRaw()` return an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` which does not have a `paginate()` method. You can create your own pagination object.

Comment: @Doom5, got it, thanks for the confirmation!