# Laravel simple select pagination with datatables

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, pagination

I am using datatables to show my data from database but let's say I have 100 000 rows in database and I run this query

```
public function listCustomers()
    {
        $customers = DB::select(DB::raw('select * from customers'));

        Log::info('Retrieving customers from database.');

        return view('customers.list', array('customers' => $customers));
    }
```

It loads forever what makes sense. Now I tried to use pagination function, but it only shows 10 rows and that's it. Only one page of rows available to display.

```
public function listCustomers()
    {
        $customers = DB::table('customers')
                    ->selectRaw('*')
                    ->paginate(10);

        Log::info('Retrieving customers from database.');

        return view('customers.list', array('customers' => $customers));
    }
```

How can I get correct pagination? I have read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968354/how-to-use-raw-sql-pagination-in-laravel5?noredirect=1&lq=1), but seems too much complicated for my case.

In both cases, I use this code to show data in my datatable:

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>

@foreach ($customers as $customer)
   <tr role="row" class="odd">                            
   <?php $i++; ?>

   <td>{{$customer->id}}</td>
   <td>{{$customer->name}}</td>
   <td>{{$customer->surname}}</td>
   <td>{{$customer->city}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your html

```
{{ $customers->links() }}
```

This will help you navigate the rest of the you data in the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this package https://packagist.org/packages/acfbentveld/laravel-datatables

`$users = DataTables::collect(User::all())->get();`
In your controller. It auto detects if datatables is requesting new data. 
In your blade or js file

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //thats all
    $('#datatable').DataTable({
        "processing": true, //process it
        "serverSide": true, //make it server side
        "ajax": location.href //Just get the data from the same url. The package will handle it all
    });

} );
```

This is very helpfull when it comes to relation search and sorting using pagination